# Prove or disprove that $φ_v:u\mapsto \langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle$ is in $V^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Let us consider a linear and continuous operator on a Hilbert space $V$, $\mathcal A:V\rightarrow V$, such that: 
$$\|\mathcal A u\|\leq M \|u\|, \ \ \forall u\in V, M>0$$
and now consider $\langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle, \ \ u,v\in V.$
We have:
$$\langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle\leq \|\mathcal A u\| \|v\|\leq M \|u\|\|v\|$$
Let $V$ be a Hilbert space, and let $V^*$ denote its dual space, consisting of all continuous linear functionals from $V$ into the field $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Prove or disprove that there exists a function $φ_v(u)$, for all $u$ in $V$ defined by
$$\varphi_v(u) = \langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle$$
and it is an element of $V^*$.

I think this is true, since linearity of the inner product and boundedness which is equivalent to continuity here, but I'm not very sure and I'm not able to provide a precise proof.

Hints are welcome.

Comment: Modified the title.

Comment: What are you unsure of? You gave all the right arguments (you still need to show that $\varphi_v$ is linear, but it's immediate. $V^*$ is "just" the set of continuous linear form, and you showed it's a continuous linear form

Comment: @Tryss. Ok. It is Riesz theorem?

Comment: No, not even Riesz theorem. You're thinking too complicated, it's really "obvious". The question can be reformulated as "prove that $\varphi_v$ is well defined, and a continuous linear form". Riesz theorem would give you a very different result (and you need the result that is asked in your question to use this theorem), and far less intuitive : for every $v \in V$, there exist $w \in V$ such that $\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, w \rangle$.

Comment: @Tryss: Thank you very much, now is more clear.

Comment: A quick remark of interest, with the Riesz theorem, you can show that there exist an unique continuous linear operator $A^*$ such that $\langle Au,v\rangle = \langle u, A^*v \rangle$. It's called the adjoint operator of $A$. So, if you look ahead about this subject, the logical steps are : 1) show that $\langle Au,v\rangle$ is a continous linear form (done here), 2) show that there exist a $w$ defined as $\langle Au,v\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle$  (Riesz theorem) 3) Show that $u \mapsto v$ is a continuous linear operator. And voila, you've defined the adjoint ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v\in V $ be fixed we defined $$\varphi_v(u) = \langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle$$

> **Claim** $u\mapsto \varphi_v(u): V\to \Bbb C$ is linear and continuous that is $\varphi_v\in V^*$

Proof:

Since $\mathcal {A}$ linear we have it follows that

$$\varphi_v(u_1+\alpha u_2) = \langle\mathcal A(u_1+\alpha u_2) , v\rangle = \langle\mathcal A(u_1)+\alpha\mathcal A( u_2) ,v\rangle\\=\langle\mathcal Au_1,v\rangle+\alpha\langle\mathcal A u_2,v\rangle = \varphi_v(u_1)+\alpha \varphi_v(u_2)$$
this prove the linearity.

On other hand since, $\mathcal A:V\to V$ is  linear and continuous we have,

$$|\varphi_v(u)|=|\langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle|\leq \|\mathcal A u\| \|v\|\leq  \|\mathcal A \|\|v\|\|u\| = K\|u\|$$
with $K=\|\mathcal A \|\|v\|$. that for all $u\in V$ we have $$|\varphi_v(u)|\le K\|u\|$$

This prove the continuity of $\varphi_v$ and hence $\varphi_v\in V^*.$